# MS Access query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Sql server doesn't have a First() function like MS Access. So how would I convert this query to work in sql server

```
SELECT 
First([MyTable].Col1) AS Col1, 
First([MyTable].Col2) As Col2, 
First([MyTable].Col3) As Col3,
First([MyTable].Col4) As Col4,
First([MyTable].Col5) As Col5,
First([MyTable].Col6) AS Col6, 
[MyTable].Col7 INTO [MyTable2]
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE ((([MyTable].OtherCol1)='S') AND (([MyTable].OtherCol2) Is Null))
GROUP BY [MyTable].Col7
HAVING ((([MyTable].Col7) Is Not Null Or ([MyTable].Col7)<>' '));
```

Comment: Where you want to use first() function? for all columns?

Comment: oops... let me correct that

Comment: @Eminem When you group by col7 What do you want `MIN, MAX or doesnt matter` of other columns?

Comment: honestly... I don't know. So I guess I have to go with doesn't matter. I'm no MS Access expert by far and I simply need to convert the query to run on sql server

Comment: "Sql server doesn't have a First() function" ...but it does have a [FIRST_VALUE windowed scalar expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
min([MyTable].Col1) AS Col1, 
min([MyTable].Col2) As Col2, 
min([MyTable].Col3) As Col3,
min([MyTable].Col4) As Col4,
min([MyTable].Col5) As Col5,
min([MyTable].Col6) AS Col6, 
[MyTable].Col7 
INTO [MyTable2]
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE ((([MyTable].OtherCol1)='S') AND (([MyTable].OtherCol2) Is Null))
GROUP BY [MyTable].Col7
HAVING ((([MyTable].Col7) Is Not Null Or ([MyTable].Col7)<>' '));
```

Comment: Why you use the Min function?

Comment: If you want data which is related to all condition which is having in where,group by and having then either we need to use min or max else you need to  group data by Col7 in innner loop and in outer loop need to add all the condition included in where and having clause